# Cleanup drivers of devices that are no longer present?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I did an upgrade on my computer running Windows 10 (1809), removed a lot of devices and add a lot of new device. I have finished installing drivers for the new devices and would like to remove the drivers for the removed devices, varying from GPU to chipset. Is there a fast or automated way to do this?

I don't care about the drivers for USB devices, because theoretically they should be cleaned-up together if the devices are not plugged-in at the moment, and such drivers are usually easy to install.

While I'm on W10 now, I'd also like to know is the solution is applicable in Windows 8 and 8.1, as well as whether the solution is applicable in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore them. Drivers for hardware not present don't get loaded. This applies to PCIe and motherboard devices just as much as USB devices.

If the driver installed a status tray icon or something like that, then you probably do want to uninstall it, to keep the process from starting. Most such processes load, discover that their device isn't there, and go away, but your system startup time and so on will probably be a little better if you remove those things.

The best way to remove drivers, or any other software, is to use Control Panel | Programs | Uninstall a program . Avoid "driver management utilities" that you find on the web.

Comment: What if the driver is installed from an INF file? I think I *could* use some `DISM.exe /Remove-Driver`...

Comment: Then it probably doesn't have anything you need to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll wait for some time before marking as accepted.

Comment: Of course. :) 

It's probably worth seeing if you can identify any such processes. One good tool for this is Process Explorer, found at sysinternals.com (actually  a Microsoft site). Enable the "Company Name" column in the processes list and look for company names like nVidia or ATI - names that match your hardware makers'.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers don't get loaded for devices that don't exist, so are not a problem
and can be ignored.

If you have phantom devices in Device Manager, right-click them and select Uninstall.
The next dialog will give you the option of also uninstalling the driver of the
device.